# Getting UDID from deactivated device without iTunes or XCode?

Tags: iphone, firmware, ios4

I installed iPhone OS 4.0 on my friends iPod Touch 3rd gen and forgot to add the udid to the provisioning portal. The device is locked and I can't seem to find a way to revert it to get the UDID. I don't have XCode here. Using iTunes, how can I revert it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the System Profiler, look under USB for your iPhone and use the serial number listed there.

Answer (score 2):

With the device connected to iTunes, click on its serial number; it should change to the UDID. You can use the Edit > Copy menu item to copy that.

Comment: It doesn't let me see that screen. It says: "Device is not part of the Developer Program."

Answer (score 0):

Piece of advise. UPPER CASE != upper case when it comes to UUID! I typed in the upper case uuid but you need to write it down in lower case.